# Mattermost TLS issue

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, mattermost

I'm having issues with TLS enabling in Mattemost. In my server I configured a lot of virtualHosts plus the mattermost files. In http everything was working fine.

Today I tried to setup TLS and https. I followed the instuctions as in https://docs.mattermost.com/install/config-tls-mattermost .html. Now I get this:

[image]

Please notice the error: I'm trying to access domain1.mywebsite.com and the error is "its security certificate is signed by domain2.mywebsite.com". domain2.mywebsite.com is one of the websites configured as virtualhosts in apache.

I did not configure any virtualhost for Mattermost, since I don't thing any is needed (and it worked flawlessly without one, and without TLS). But how can I tell mattermost (or the browser?) that the server of domain2.mywebsite.com is the same of domain1.mywebsite.com?

I generated the certificates using letsencrypt with the standalone option (`sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d domain1.mywebsite.com`) and didn't move any file, just enabled "UseLetsEncrypt": true, in config.json file.

Do you happen to have any idea about how I could fix this?

Thank you
Marco

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to configure TLS on Apache. You'll needs to use separate certificates for each virtual host.

Here is information that might help you: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html

Don't configure TLS on Mattermost if TLS is being handled by the proxy.